# trouble with: cannot set using a multi-index selection indexer with a different length than the value

Tags: python, pandas

I'm having trouble at the minue with the following error:

```
ValueError: cannot set using a multi-index selection indexer with a different length than the value
```

which is directed specifically at

```
d.loc[(d['X'] <xo)  & (d['Y'] > yo) & (d['Y'] < yo*2), 'Start'] = dfc1.loc[1].values
```

here is the value of `d`

```
        Match      X      Y     end_X   end_Y   xG     ID   player             team           action         half
0   Motherwell  31.1    5.5     23.9    15.3    0.0     7   6. P.McGinn     Hibernian   Passes accurate     1st half
1   Motherwell  33.1    12.7    34.6    2.9     0.0     9   5. R.Porteous   Hibernian   Passes accurate     1st half
2   Motherwell  35.0    4.7     25.5    15.7    0.0     11  6. P.McGinn     Hibernian   Passes accurate     1st half
3   Motherwell  24.2    16.5    8.3     30.4    0.0     12  5. R.Porteous   Hibernian   Passes accurate     1st half
4   Motherwell  4.2     58.0    60.8    64.8    0.0     35  16. L.Stevenson     Hibernian   Passes accurate     1st half
```

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

xo = 6.5625
yo = 5.66

dfc1 = {1:[0.001,0.002,0.002,0.002,0.003,0.004,0.004,0.004,0.002,0.002,0.002,0.001]}
dfc1 = pd.DataFrame(dfc1)



d.loc[(d['X'] < xo) & (d['Y'] < yo), 'Start'] = dfc1.loc[0].values
d.loc[(d['X'] <xo)  & (d['Y'] > yo) & (d['Y'] < yo*2), 'Start'] = dfc1.loc[1].values
d.loc[(d['X']<xo) &(d['Y'] > yo*2) & (d['Y'] < yo*3), 'Start'] = dfc1.loc[2].values
d.loc[(d['X']<xo) &(d['Y'] > yo*3) & (d['Y'] < yo*4), 'Start'] = dfc1.loc[3].values
d.loc[(d['X']<xo) &(d['Y'] > yo*4) & (d['Y'] > yo*5), 'Start'] = dfc1.loc[4].values
d.loc[(d['X']<xo) &(d['Y'] > yo*5) & (d['Y'] > yo*6), 'Start'] = dfc1.loc[5].values
d.loc[(d['X']<xo) &(d['Y'] > yo*6) & (d['Y'] > yo*7), 'Start'] = dfc1.loc[6].values
d.loc[(d['X']<xo) &(d['Y'] > yo*7) & (d['Y'] > yo*8), 'Start'] = dfc1.loc[7].values
d.loc[(d['X']<xo) &(d['Y'] > yo*8) & (d['Y'] > yo*9), 'Start'] = dfc1.loc[8].values
d.loc[(d['X']<xo) &(d['Y'] > yo*9) & (d['Y'] > yo*10), 'Start'] = dfc1.loc[9].values
d.loc[(d['X']<xo) &(d['Y'] > yo*10) & (d['Y'] > yo*11), 'Start'] = dfc1.loc[10].values
d.loc[(d['X']<xo) &(d['Y'] > yo*11) & (d['Y'] > yo*12), 'Start'] = dfc1.loc[11].values
```

After looking on here for answers I'm still struggling to get my head around it. Any help?

expected output would be something like;

```
       Match      X      Y     end_X   end_Y   xG     ID   player             team           action         half   Start 
0   Motherwell  31.1    5.5     23.9    15.3    0.0     7   6. P.McGinn     Hibernian   Passes accurate     1st half 0.002
1   Motherwell  33.1    12.7    34.6    2.9     0.0     9   5. R.Porteous   Hibernian   Passes accurate     1st half 0.002
2   Motherwell  35.0    4.7     25.5    15.7    0.0     11  6. P.McGinn     Hibernian   Passes accurate     1st half 0.001
3   Motherwell  24.2    16.5    8.3     30.4    0.0     12  5. R.Porteous   Hibernian   Passes accurate     1st half 0.004
4   Motherwell  4.2     58.0    60.8    64.8    0.0     35  16. L.Stevenson     Hibernian   Passes accurate     1st half 0.004
```

Comment: Please share what is expected output ?

Comment: It is just a snippit of my code, I have about 190 lines of the ```d.loc``` code. What I'm trying to do is 'if X is below a specific number and Y is above a specific number' then it will return the value of the dfc1.loc[] in a new column

Comment: Without actual expected output i wont be able to help you here, just write it manually in table format and add it to your qustion..

Comment: I've updated the opening post at the bottom with an example of expected outcome, but because I'm unable to run the code - i'm unable to give the exact outcome.